# Define different META template per page/post template

Tags: php, templates, wordpress, seo

I would like to setup different META syntax on my Wordpress website, depending on the template I use (5 templates for pages and 8 templates for articles.
I use SEO by yoast that only gives the possibility to add ONE META syntax for all pages oand one for ALL articles.
I tried add use this on my function.php for one template (example)

```
$pref_nom = get_post_meta($post->ID, $pref_nom, true);

function prefecture_filter_wp_title( $title ) {

    if ( is_page_template( 'pages-prefectures.php' ) ) {
        return $pref_nom;
    }

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'prefecture_filter_wp_title' );
```

But I doesn't work (notice that $pref_nom is not declared)

What's wrong ?

### Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It's a wordpress specific question, add `wordpress` and `worpdress-plugin` tags to it.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you mean by meta syntax, and I'm not sure what $pref_nom is supposed to be or what you are trying to accomplish with this specific code.

If all you want to do is have different meta fields for different page templates, use the Advanced Custom Fields plugin. It will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: What I would like to do is : 

For Page template X setup the following title : 
Title : $myvariable1 - blabla : $myvariable2 and $myvariable3

For page template Y :
title : $myvariable2 - other blabla, $myvariable4 

For page template Z :
title : $myvariable4 - Yet another blabla, $myvariable3

The variables I would like to use would be some custom fiels values